# Formatting multi line strings in Python

Tags: python, pycharm

Using this Pseudocode:
1. Declare Number As Float
2. Declare Root As Float
3. Declare Response As Character
4. Write `Do you want to find the square root of a number?`
5. Write `Enter ‘y’ for yes, ‘n’ for no:`

---

What I have coded:

```
Response = str(input('Do you want to find the square root of a number? \ 
       Enter y for yes, n for no: '))
```

Output in PyCharm Run Window:

Do you want to find the square root of a number?            Enter y for yes, n for no:

Format Result wanted:

```
Do you want to find the square root of a number?            
Enter y for yes, n for no:
```

Comment: All you have to do is put a `\n` instead of a `\ `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can print a line wrap with `\n`.

Example:

```
Response = input('Do you want to find the square root of a number?\nEnter y for yes, n for no: ')
```

Output:

```
Do you want to find the square root of a number?
Enter y for yes, n for no:
```

Answer (score 1):

Your almost there. You just missed a '\n' in your string that your trying to print. This prints your string in the right format:

```
Response = str(input('Do you want to find the square root of a number?\nEnter y for yes, n for no: '))
```

Comment: Passing the result of `input()` into `str()` is not necessary as `input()` returns a `string` so the conversion is absolute. Out of interest, what data type did you think `input()` returned?

Comment: In python 3.x input works like raw_input(), which always returns a string. But in python 2.7 input() returns the type of the type of whatever expression the user types in. It's better to use raw_input() instead of input() in Python 2.7. There was nothing mentioned about the version of python being used, so I think it's better to have the str() if it's Python2.7. If it's Python 3.0, str() is not required.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `newline` character as said by `@MikeScotty`, or you could define the message first using a `multi-line` `string`. This makes changing and creating the message easier than typing in `\n` over and over again.

To do this, use `triple-quoted` `strings`:

```
m = """Do you want to find the square root of a number?
Enter y for yes, n for no: """
```

and then you can simply do:

```
input(m)
```

---

Which would prompt the user with:

```
Do you want to find the square root of a number?
Enter y for yes, n for no: [their entry ready here]
```

---

Of course, you don't need to define `m` (the message) separately, you can just write that `triple-quoted` `string` directly as the parameter for `input`, but things can start to get a bit messy:

```
Response = input("""Do you want to find the square root of a number?
Enter y for yes, n for no: """)
```

Comment: awesome!  Thank you for showing me another way of doing this.  The more tools the better!

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `\n` not just `\` . N represent the 'new line'.